# How to use SSS texture in Blender?

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor, shaders, subsurface-scattering

How do I properly connect the SSS texture in a Blender using nodes?

Answer (score 1):

If the texture is a black and white image, chances are that it is supposed to drive the **Subsurface Amount**. Simply connect the **Color Output** to the **Subsurface Input** in the Principled Shader. If the image is colored, connect it to the **Subsurface Color** input to drive the Color of subsurface.

Here is an image of how to connect the nodes (assuming you have a black and white texture):[image: Node Setup]
The top setup is basic, and the bottom setup gives you more control over the amount of subsurface by adjusting the ColorRamp.

Comment: I have a black and white texture. Could you show in practice a screenshot of how to do this?